# xscreensaver screenlock Couldn't Grab Pointer - Already Grabbed

Tags: lxde, screen-lock, xscreensaver

Running lxde and lxpanel on Debian 8.1. `xdotool key "XF86LogGrabInfo"` lists no actively grabbed devices in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Clicking the Screenlock icon in the application launch bar has a long delay before activating screenlock and fails to grab the mouse, with the error "couldn't grab pointer (AlreadyGrabbed). It fails to detect mouse movement to wake up the screensaver and doesn't intercept mouse events.

The command `xscreensaver-command -lock` works properly so I've tried the following:

`/etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel` shows:

```
Plugin {
    type = launchbar
    Config {
        Button {
            id=lxde-screenlock.desktop
        }
        Button {
            id=lxde-logout.desktop
        }
    }
}
```

`/usr/share/applications/lxde-screenlock.desktop` shows it is executing `lxlock`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=ScreenLock
Name[es]=Bloqueo de pantalla
Name[pt_BR]=Bloquear tela
Name[ru]=Блокировка экрана
Name[tr]=ScreenLock
Name[uk]=Блокування екрану
Name[zh_TW]=鎖住螢幕
Comment=Lock your screen
Comment[es]=Bloquear pantalla
Comment[pt_BR]=Bloqueie sua tela
Comment[ru]=Заблокировать экран
Comment[tr]=Ekranı kilitle
Comment[uk]=Заблокувати екран
Icon=system-lock-screen
Exec=lxlock
TryExec=lxlock
NoDisplay=true
```

Edited `lxde-screenlock.desktop` to execute `xscreensaver-command --lock` instead of `lxlock`:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/xscreensaver-command -lock
TryExec=/usr/bin/xscreensaver-command
```

Even though I've changed the desktop entry file and the lxsession configuration's lockscreen manager to `xscreensaver-command -lock` it lags and fails to grab the mouse when using the tray icon. I've restarted the lxsession and confirmed that this desktop entry is being used by the tray icon.

Update:
I've also tried adding the `Lock Screen (XScreenSaver)` menu item from the Debian section of the application menu to lxpanel's application launchbar. The problem persists. Screen lock functions properly when run by any other method (terminal, application menu, and LXDE logout menu), so I am inclined to call it a bug caused by lxpanel.

Edit: I'm currently using an openbox keybinding to execute `xscreensaver-command -lock` as a work around, but I would still like to determine why running it from the application launcher fails.